# Convertir cadenas con caracteres especiales como tildes a letras normal

Tags: python

Estoy contando la cantidad de veces que se repite x letra en un texto, pero la u se cuenta por separado como u y ü, me gustaría saber como puedo pasar ese tipo de letras a la tradicional y contarlas uniformemente

el codigo que tengo es este:

```
#FRECUENCIA DE LAS LETRAS 
suma = 0
extra = "1234567890"
total = defaultdict(int)
with open("CIEN AÑOS DE SOLEDAD.txt", "r") as archivo:
    for linea in archivo.readlines():
        for letra in linea.lower():
            if letra.isalpha() or letra in extra:
                total[letra] += 1
                suma += 1
            
print(suma)
for letra, cuenta in total.items():
    print("Símbolo: ",letra,"|","Ocurrencias en el texto: ", cuenta, "valor","|","Frecuencia, %",round((cuenta/suma)*100,2))
```

salida:

```
Símbolo:  g | Ocurrencias en el texto:  6682 valor | Frecuencia, % 1.01
Símbolo:  a | Ocurrencias en el texto:  87365 valor | Frecuencia, % 13.26
Símbolo:  b | Ocurrencias en el texto:  11536 valor | Frecuencia, % 1.75
Símbolo:  r | Ocurrencias en el texto:  45391 valor | Frecuencia, % 6.89
Símbolo:  i | Ocurrencias en el texto:  36649 valor | Frecuencia, % 5.56
Símbolo:  e | Ocurrencias en el texto:  81154 valor | Frecuencia, % 12.32
Símbolo:  l | Ocurrencias en el texto:  39410 valor | Frecuencia, % 5.98
Símbolo:  c | Ocurrencias en el texto:  26945 valor | Frecuencia, % 4.09
Símbolo:  í | Ocurrencias en el texto:  5174 valor | Frecuencia, % 0.79
Símbolo:  m | Ocurrencias en el texto:  17171 valor | Frecuencia, % 2.61
Símbolo:  á | Ocurrencias en el texto:  2040 valor | Frecuencia, % 0.31
.....
```

Comment: https://cmsdk.com/python/remove-accents-and-keep-under-dots-in-python.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usar regex puede ser algo overkill para hacer lo que buscas. Python ofrece formas de cambiar un carácter por otro en una cadena sin importar más modulos. Estos son los métodos [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) y [translate](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) de las cadenas.

###### Codigo

```
# Aqui se concatenan cadenas para formar una sola cadena con todas las vocales que tengan tildes.
# La \ significa "esta suma sigue en la siguiente linea".
# Esto genera "àáâãäåèéêëìíîïòóôõöùúûü"

tildes = ("àáâãäå" + \
          "èéêë" + \
          "ìíîï" + \
          "òóôõö" + \
          "ùúûü")

# Cada letra aquí corresponde a una vocal acentuada.
# Por ejemplo la primera "a" corresponde a "à", la segunda con "á" y asi sucesivamente.

vocales = ("aaaaaa" + \
           "eeee" + \
           "iiii" + \
           "ooooo" + \
           "uuuu")

# Aqui con el método maketrans relacionamos las dos cadenas antes creadas.
# Esto devuelve un diccionario compatible con el método translate.
quitatildes = str.maketrans(tildes, vocales)

cadena = "Hólã mûndo esta ès üna cadena"

# Teniendo ese diccionario generado (solo hace falta crearlo una vez)
# podemos usar el método translate para cambiar las vocales acentuadas con vocales sin acentuar.
cadena = cadena.translate(quitatildes)

print(cadena)
```

###### Produce

```
Hola mundo esta es una cadena
```

Nota: Esta solución no cambia vocales acentuadas en mayúscula. Si querés afectar las que están en mayuscula, tendrás que agregar esas vocales acentuadas en mayuscula con sus respectivas versiones sin acentuar.

Answer (score 4):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar `Unidecode`. Si no lo tienes instálalo con

```
pip install Unidecode
```

Unidecode cambia las letras por la más cercana, por ejemplo `á` lo cambiaría por `a`

Ejemplo funcionando:

```
import unidecode
print(unidecode.unidecode('kožušček'))
```

Salida:

```
kozuscek
```

Otra opción es utilizar `Regex` (Del inglés Regular Expresions)

```
import re
def quitar_acentos(old):
  new = old.lower()
  new = re.sub(r'[àáâãäå]', 'a', new)
  new = re.sub(r'[èéêë]', 'e', new)
  new = re.sub(r'[ìíîï]', 'i', new)
  new = re.sub(r'[òóôõö]', 'o', new)
  new = re.sub(r'[ùúûü]', 'u', new)
  return new

print(quitar_acentos('áêìöù'))
```

Otra opción es utilizar `replace()` pero en mi opinión sería la peor solución

```
def quitar_acentos(old):
  new = old.replace('á', 'a')
  # Y hacer lo mismo para cada letra que quieras reemplazar
  return new

print(quitar_acentos('más'))
```

Comment: ¿es necesario instalarlo, no hay otra forma en la cual no se deba instalar nada?

Comment: @JohnJames, Edité la respuesta con otras 2 opciones pero yo creo que lo mejor sería utilizar `Unidecode`. No hace falta reinventar la rueda

Comment: Vale, si creo que la mejor opción es la primera. Muchas gracias, feliz dia

Answer (score 2):

Te propongo un snippet que tengo siempre a mano:

```
sust = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, u'\u0300\u0301\u0302\u0308'), None)
cadena = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', cadena).translate(sust)
```

La explicación es sencilla descomponemos los caracteres unicode y eliminamos los diacríticos 0300 (`), 0301 (´), 0302 (^) y 0308 (¨).

En caso de trabajar con textos en otros idiomas habría que ampliar el listado de caracteres para ajustarlo a tus necesidades