# Duda sobre tildes en python por consola

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo una duda, como ven en el código sencillito se mete info por consola y esta la valida si la info es correcta o no, mi duda es la siguiente, cuando un código parecido a esto se lleva a producción un % de personas lo escribe correctamente pero otro % de personas lo escribe  sin  tildes así sin más, un ejemplo: ("informática gráfica" es correcta pero también es correcta "informatica grafica" hablando de información) ahora lo que me gustaría es que el código acepte si cuando introduzcan por consola la información y lo hagan sin tildes también les de por valido la información introducida, no solo para esas palabras si no para todas las posibles que lleven tildes, me refiero para a futuro cuando cree un programa más complicado.

Tengo entendido que es algo del formato **utf-8** pero no se como aplicarlo en el código, aquí abajo les dejo un ejemplo.

```html
print ("Asignaturas Optativas")

print ("Informática Gráfica - Pruebas  de Software - Usabilidad y Accesibilidad")

opcion = input ("Escribe la asignatura escogida: ")

asignatura = opcion.lower()

if asignatura in ("informática gráfica", "pruebas de software", "usabilidad y accesibildiad"):

    print ("La asignatura elegida es:", asignatura)

else:

    print ("La asignatura no está disponible")
```

Comment: Buen día, [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/518168/171630) hay una pregunta que se relaciona a la tuya, usando alguno de los métodos mencionados en las respuestas puedes convertir cadenas de caracteres con tildes a letras normales.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes sustituir las tildes y diéresis de la entrada y así podrás evaluarlo contra tu lista:

```
import unicodedata

def quitar_tildes(cadena):
    sust = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, u'\u0300\u0301\u0302\u0308'), None)
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', cadena).translate(sust)


print("Asignaturas Optativas")

print("Informática Gráfica - Pruebas  de Software - Usabilidad y Accesibilidad")

opcion = input("Escribe la asignatura escogida: ")

asignatura = quitar_tildes(opcion.lower())

# ahora establecemos tus strings sin tildes de ningun tipo
asignaturas = [quitar_tildes(_) for _ in ["informática gráfica", "pruebas de software", "usabilidad y accesibildiad"]]

    print("La asignatura elegida es:", asignatura)

else:

    print("La asignatura no está disponible")
```

Tienes la explicación de la función `quitar_tildes()` en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/518218/3610)

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo esta solución:

```
lista_asignaturas = ["Informática Gráfica", "Pruebas  de Software", "Usabilidad y Accesibilidad", "Salir"]

for counter, value in enumerate(lista_asignaturas):
    print(counter, value)      
# solicitamos una opción de valor al usuario
opcion_elegida = int (input("\nSeleccione una asignatura  \n") )
asignatura = lista_asignaturas[opcion_elegida]
print ("\n Has elegido : ", asignatura)
if opcion_elegida == 3:
    exit()        
elif opcion_elegida > 3 :
    input("\nNo has pulsado ninguna opción correcta...\npulsa una tecla para continuar\n")
```

De esta manera, colamente tendrán que contestar introsuciendo 0, 1 2 o 3