# Juego de ahorcado, duda

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un juego de "ahorcado" el cual consiste en ingresar una frase y un grupo de letras separadas por comas a modo de intentos. Esta frase debe revelar una de sus letras cada vez que un intento sea correcto, si es incorrecto debe ubicarse en el ultimo modulo.

Cada intento se debe ubicar de esta forma en estos tres módulos e irse actualizando hasta que se cumpla la condición de que si la cantidad de intentos incorrectos, es igual a la división entera de la longitud la frase se marque al final, PERDIÓ. De lo contrario se marque GANÓ. Ejemplo:

[Letra] - [Frase en "?"] - [letra incorrecta]

```
Inputs:

-->INGRESARFRASE: El Padrino
-->Intento: v,g,a,s,B,C

Output:

[V] - [?? ???????] - [V]
[A] - [?? ?A?????] - [V]
[G] - [?? ?A?????] - [VG]
[S] - [?? ?A?????] - [VGS]
[B] - [?? ?A?????] - [VGSB]
PERDIÓ
```

Mi duda es la siguiente, consigo hacer que todo esto se haga de forma individual (ingresando dato por dato) en intento. Sin embargo al momento de introducir el grupo de datos separados por coma (v,g,a,s,B,C) me genera esta salida.

```
INGRESARFRASE: El Padrino
[] - [?? ???????] - []: v,g,a,s,B,C
[V,G,A,S,B,C] - [?? ???????] - [V,G,A,S,B,C]:
```

Considero que el problema puede estar aquí el cual no me esta comparando cada uno individualmente con la frase.:

```
def descubrirFrase(frase,incognita,intento):
  for i in range(len(frase)):
      if frase[i] == intento:
        incognita[i] = intento
```

Mi código es este:

```
def limpiar(s):
  return s.upper().replace("Á","A").replace("É","E").replace("Í","I").replace("Ó","O").replace("Ú","U")

def transformarIncognita(frase):
  incognita = []
  for i in frase:
    if i == ' ':
      incognita.append(' ')
      continue

    incognita.append('?')
  return (incognita) 

def descubrirFrase(frase,incognita,intento):
  for i in range(len(frase)):
      if frase[i] == intento:
        incognita[i] = intento

frase = limpiar(input("INGRESAR FRASE: "))
incognita = transformarIncognita(frase)
intento = ""
intentosFallidos = []

while True:
  if intento in frase:
    descubrirFrase(frase,incognita,intento)
  else:
    intentosFallidos.append(intento)

  incognita_str = "".join(incognita)

  if incognita_str == frase:
    print('GANÓ')
    break
  elif len(intentosFallidos) == len(frase) // 2:
    print("PERDIÓ")
    break

  print("[%s] - [%s] - [%s]: " % (intento,incognita_str,"".join(intentosFallidos)), end = "")
  intento = limpiar(input())
```

Gracias de antemano por su tiempo si pueden ayudarme con esta duda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación

De hecho, estás en lo cierto.

Cuando recorres el rango con el bucle for, obtienes cada caracter de la frase. Por supuesto, un solo caracter NUNCA va a ser igual a una cadena más larga.

Ejemplo: En algún momento, tu bucle for llegará a la letra "A", y "A" no es igual a "V,G,A,S,B,C".

#### Solución

Lo mejor es que utilices otro tipo de dato. Yo creo que el más conveniente sería una lista, ya que Python ofrece una forma de convertir cadenas a listas: [str.split](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Python también nos ofrece el operador in, que se encarga de buscar si algo está dentro de otra cosa.

Y también están las [comprensiones de lista](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/comprension-de-listas-y-otras-colecciones/), para crear otra lista a partir de un iterador (como por ejemplo otra lista). Son una simplificación de un bucle for.

```
def descubrirFrase(frase,incognita,intento):
  intento = [limpiar(x) for x in intento.split(",")]

  for i in range(len(frase)):
      if frase[i] in intento:
        incognita[i] = frase[i]
```

#### Nuevo problema

Ahora, seguirá sin funcionar, ya que en esta sección:

```
if intento in frase:
```

Se estará buscando una cadena que en muchos casos no estará en frase, por lo que dará False a pesar de que hay letras. Como "v,g,a,s,B,C" en "El Padrino".

#### Solución definitiva

Yo reescribiría la función para que recorra todos los intentos uno por uno, los ubique y devuelva todos los intentos fallidos:

```
def descubrirFrase(frase,incognita,intento):
  intentos_fallidos = []

  for intento in intento:
    intento = limpiar(intento)
    encontrado = False
      
    for i in range(len(frase)):
      if frase[i] == intento:
        encontrado = True
        incognita[i] = intento

    if(not encontrado):
        intentos_fallidos.append(intento)

  return intentos_fallidos
```

Y esta parte:

```
if intento in frase:
  descubrirFrase(frase,incognita,intento)
else:
  intentosFallidos.append(intento)
```

La cambiaría por:

```
intentos_fallidos = descubrirFrase(frase,incognita,intento)
intentosFallidos.extend(intentos_fallidos)
```

El método extend toma un iterador (como otra lista) y agrega los nuevos items al final.

#### Produce

```
INGRESAR FRASE: el padrino
[] - [?? ???????] - []: v,g,a,s,B,C
[V,G,A,S,B,C] - [?? ?A?????] - [VGSBC]:
```

#### Una pequeña recomendación

Uno de los trabajos de tu función limpiar es quitar las tildes. Hay mejores formas de hacerlo en lugar de usar un montón de replaces. Te recomiendo leer las respuestas a esta pregunta: [Convertir cadenas con caracteres especiales como tildes a letras normal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/518168/158880)

Comment: Ok. Muchas gracias.