# ¿Como reemplazo varios caracteres de una lista str en python?

Tags: python, string, str-replace

Estoy construyendo una funcion que lea un archivo,reemplaze las vocales con acentos por vocales y segun su numero de caracteres se guarden en una lista especifica.
mi pregunta es: ¿con el metodo replace(), ¿puedo reemplazar varios caracteres o hay otra forma de implementar el metodo?
'''

```
def read():
    with open ("./word.txt","r", encoding="utf=8") as f:
            list_word = [line for line in f] 
            #agregarlo a nueva lista
            wordsf = []   
            wordsm = []
            wordd = []
            words = []
            for line in list_word:
                #reemplazar caracter de la lista
                result = line.replace('\n','')
                result = line.replace('á,é,í,ó,ú','a,e,i,o,u')
                words.append(result)
    
    print(random.choice(words))
```

'''

Comment: `replace` no te sirve en este caso (a menos que hagas un `replace` por cada vocal). Puedes usar el método `translate` para hacerlo con una sola instrucción.

Comment: Es mala idea leer todo el archivo de una vez. También es innecesario; puedes leer una línea, procesarla y grabarla antes de pasar a la siguiente.

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135707/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-reemplazar-las-letras-con-tildes-por-las-mismas-sin-tilde-pero-no-l?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: En mi opinión, una de las mejores formas sin complicarse mucho y sin modulos adicionales es el uso de maketrans y translate como muestro en [una de mis respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/518205/158880)

Answer (score 0):

En python, las cadenas de caracteres son *"inmutables"*, no listas. Cuando se usa `str.replace()` en realidad estás construyendo una cadena nueva, sin modificar la cadena original.

Para reemplazar caracteres en la cadena lo mejor ir revisando letra a letra y reconstruir la cadena, para lo que va muy bien la *compresión de listas* y el método `"".join()`:

```py
vocales = {
    'á':'a',
    'é':'e',
    'í':'i',
    'ó':'o',
    'ú':'u',    
}

def cambia_vocales(s: str) -> str:
    return "".join(vocales.get(c, c) for c in s)
```

El método `dict.get()` obtiene un elemento del diccionario. `vocales.get(c)` es equivalente a `vocales[c]`, pero permite añadir un valor para cuando no se encuentre el índice en el diccionario.

O sea, `vocales.get(c, c)` sería equivalente a `vocales[c] if c in vocales else c`, pero más concreto.

Con `"".join()` volvemos a reconstruir la cadena a partir de sus letras.